# Set owner of OpenFileDialog from window handle

Tags: c#, wpf, common-dialog

I would like to set the owner of the [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) (within namespace `Microsoft.Win32` not `System.Windows.Forms`) but I only have the handle ([IntPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr(v=vs.110).aspx)) of the window (the handle doesn't have to be from my application it could be an external).

Is that possible or am I forced to use the [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) from `System.Windows.Forms`?

I want to have the effect of calling the

```cs
protected abstract bool RunDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner);
```

inside the base class [CommonDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.commondialog(v=vs.110).aspx), but it's protected. Is there a way around? Could I use reflection to get this method and execute it, or is there a "cleaner" way to do it?

The normal `ShowDialog()` method only allows a `Window`, which is something I don't have.

I use this code to set the owner of other window when I only have the handle, but the constructor of `WindowInteropHelper` only takes a `Window` and `CommondDialog` doesn't inherit from `Window`:

```cs
Window window;
IntPtr ownerHwnd;
var wih = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
wih.Owner = ownerHwnd;
```

Comment: I think you're stuffed, as the dialogs are sealed so you can't even derive from them and inject your own handle when `RunDialog` is called.  The WinForms versions wrap the same native dialogs, so that's probably the best option.

Comment: You can cheat and use MethodInfo.Invoke() to execute RunDialog.  Trying that hard to avoid the winforms version isn't very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this question is still a duplicate of *some* Stack Overflow question, but I didn't find an obvious closely-matching candidate in a quick search. So…

You can obtain a WPF `Window` object by casting the `RootVisual` property value of an `HwndSource` to `Window`:

```
Window IntPtrToWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd);

    return (Window)hwndSource.RootVisual;
}
```

See [HwndSource Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Does this work with external hwnds?
So for example I write an add-in for an PDF reader (or other random program) and call my C# method with this code do I really get a WPF Window object?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "external". For sure, it should work for any HWND from the same process. Sharing handles across processes can be tricky, but assuming you have a valid HWND that you would otherwise be able to use (e.g. send messages to), it would probably work there as well. Easy enough for you to try though.

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks for the answer gona come back eventually.
And yeah I meant from different processes.